# Making a Generic single linked list in C. Copy unknown data (void) to a pointer within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, memcpy, void-pointers

I'm trying to make a single linked list in C able to store different type of data. i.e. I want to save floats in the list, but also structs in the same list. My main problem (as far as I know) is the memcpy used in node.c to copy the received data by the user to a pointer within the TNode struct.

list.h

```
#include "node.h"

typedef struct {
       TNode *h;
       TNode *t;
       int tamInfo;
    } TList;
```

***list.c***

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

/*Function to store a TList reserving enough space dynamically*/

TList* newList(int tamInfo) {
    TList *list = (TList*)malloc(sizeof(TList)); 
    list->h = list->t = NULL;
    list->tamInfo = tamInfo;
    return list;
}

/*This function receives the type of list   "Tlist* list", 
and the information to store in it "void*  info" (see  main.c)*/

void addNode(TList* lis, void* info) {
    TNode *p = createNode(lis,info);
    if (lis->h == NULL) {
        lis->h = p;
        lis->t = p;
        return;
    }
    else {
        TNode* punt = lis->h;
        while (punt->s != NULL) {
            punt = punt->s;
        }
        punt->s = p;
    }
}
```

node.h:

```
struct Node{
    void *dato;
    struct Node *s;
};
typedef struct Node TNode;
```

***node.c***

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "nod.h"

/* This function receives "void* dato" which is a struct TList, 
and "int tam" which depends on the main.c (it can be a float, int or even a string) */

TNode* createNode(void* dato, int tam) {
    TNode *q = (TNode*)malloc(sizeof(TNode));
    q->dato = malloc(sizeof(tam));
    q->s = NULL;

/* q->dato = tam; If I do it this way, it works in some cases. But I want to make it work in all cases, i.e. when using strings */

    memcpy((void*)q->dato, tam, sizeof(tam)); // I've tried using memcpy(q->dato, dato, sizeof(dato)); and other variations such as   memcpy(q->dato, tam, sizeof(tam));
    printf("q->dato = %lf\n", *(double*)q->dato); //First I'm using this to print it as a float value (I send a float number in the variable tam)
    return q;
}
```

***main.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

typedef struct {
    char Name[20];
    int age;
} TPersona;

}

int main()
{
    TList *listN, *listP;
    double x;
    TPersona p, *q;
    char r;

    listN = newList(sizeof(double));
    listP = newList(sizeof(TPersona));


    do {
        printf("Give me a real number: ");
        scanf("%lf",&x);
        if (x>=0) {
            addNode(listN,&x);
        }
    } while (x>=0);

    do {
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s",p.Name);
        printf("Age: ");
        scanf("%d",&(p.age));
        if (p.age>0)
            addNode(listP,&p);

    } while (p.age>0);
```

Comment: the second argument of `memcpy` should be a pointer

Comment: Yes. I've tried using memcpy(q->dato,dato,sizeof(dato)); but it doesn't work. dato is a void*

Comment: there is no `dato` in `createNode`

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, mind blanked there.

Comment: Anyways, the first argument is the destination, the second argument is the source.  That is where the data is being copied from.  You need to figure out what your source should be and then get a pointer to it (perhaps `&tam`?)  I don't believe that will be the end of your problems, though.

Comment: You have both a `head` and `tail` pointer (initialized in `TList* newList(int tamInfo)`) -- why on earth are you iterating to the end to add the new node? (e.g. `while (punt->s != NULL)`) -- which loses your tail pointer....See [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)